# Layouting and Input Transparency within Grid

Tags: maui

in my .NET MAUI App, I use the following Grid within a **ContentView**. The intention is to have this BackgroundImage and above that I want to have the ScrollView. On the Scroll view there should be several Frames containing some other UI elements like Entry, Button etc.

The current code looks as follows:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto">

    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Source="radiant_gradient.png" 
           Aspect="AspectFill" />

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>
    </ScrollView>


    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" >
        <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" Background="{StaticResource White}" Opacity="0.9" HeightRequest="65"
           HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="10" Margin="15,-490,15,15" Padding="0">

            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Margin="15, 15, 15, 15">
                <picker:CustomPickerControl Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedMealName, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate CustomPickerControl_Placeholder}" BorderColor="{x:StaticResource Gray400}" Padding="0, 0, 25, 0" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <!--Save Button-->
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate SaveMealButton_Text}" Command="{Binding SaveMealCommand}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="100" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="15, 7, 15, 10"/>
            </Grid>

        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>

    <!--- ... more Frames planned here for Rows 2 and 3 -->
</Grid>
```

When I use a Stacklayout or any other Layout, it positions my Frame as I want it, but I neither can focus my Entry nor click the Save-Button:

[image]

When I just use the Frame without surrounding LayoutManager, I can focus my Entry and click the Save-Button, but it does not position it correctly and it is moved downwards:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto">

    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Source="radiant_gradient.png" 
           Aspect="AspectFill" />

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>
    </ScrollView>


    <Frame Grid.Row="1" BorderColor="LightGray" Background="{StaticResource White}" Opacity="0.9" HeightRequest="65"
           HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="10" Margin="15,-490,15,15" Padding="0">

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Margin="15, 15, 15, 15">
            <picker:CustomPickerControl Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedMealName, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate CustomPickerControl_Placeholder}" BorderColor="{x:StaticResource Gray400}" Padding="0, 0, 25, 0" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

            <!--Save Button-->
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate SaveMealButton_Text}" Command="{Binding SaveMealCommand}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="100" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="15, 7, 15, 10"/>
        </Grid>

    </Frame>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Well, what is absolutely necessary that I can use the underlying controls within the Frame (an Entry and the Save-Button).

What am I doing wrong here?

=================== Added Parent Page for the View regarding comment ========================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.Pages.Views"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:tabs="http://sharpnado.com"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XGENO.Maui.Controls;assembly=Maui.Controls.BottomSheet"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="OptimizerApp.Pages.MainPage"
             Title="{loc:Translate Calculate_Title}">


    <!-- Styles for the BottomTabs -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BottomTab" TargetType="tabs:BottomTabItem">
                <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansExtraBold" />
                <Setter Property="UnselectedLabelColor" Value="{StaticResource Black}" />
                <Setter Property="UnselectedIconColor" Value="{StaticResource Black}" />
                <Setter Property="IconSize" Value="24" />
                <Setter Property="LabelSize" Value="14" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:CalculateViewModel x:Key="CalculateViewModel" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    
    
    <Grid IgnoreSafeArea="True">

        <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 55">
            
            <!--Switcher to switch between the different Views-->
            <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                               Animate="True"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:CalculateView"
                                BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}"
                                AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                Animate="True"                              
                                UseActivityIndicator="True" />

                <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:OverviewView"
                                BindingContext="{Binding Source={viewModels:OverviewViewModel}}"
                                AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                Animate="True"
                                UseActivityIndicator="True" />

            </tabs:ViewSwitcher>

            <!--Tabs at the Bottom-->
            <tabs:TabHostView x:Name="TabHost"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              BackgroundColor="White"
                              Orientation="Horizontal"
                              TabType="Fixed"
                              SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
                    <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                        IconImageSource="1.png"
                                        Label="{loc:Translate AppShell_Calculate}"
                                        Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                    <!--Circle button to add new Items to CalculateView-->
                    <tabs:TabButton x:Name="CalculateAddCircleButton"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    ButtonCircleSize="110"
                                    IconImageSource="2.png"
                                    TapCommand="{Binding Source={StaticResource  CalculateViewModel}, Path=DisplayBottomSheetCommand}"
                                    TranslationY="-15" />


                    <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                        IconImageSource="3.png"
                                        Label="{loc:Translate AppShell_Overview}" />

                </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
            </tabs:TabHostView>

        </Grid>

        
        
        <controls:BottomSheet x:Name="BottomSheet"
                              HeaderText="{loc:Translate BottomSheet_AddToHeader}"                              
                              BottomSheetClosed="BottomSheet_Closed"
                              SheetHeight="600"
                              InputTransparent="True">

            <!--The content of the BottomSheet is defined in an own View-->
            <controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>
                <views:BottomSheetContentView BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}" />
            </controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>

        </controls:BottomSheet>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I put the code you shared into a  contentView, but I couldn't see the controls(e.g. the save `Button`)  on the screen.  Could you please post more code snippets so that we can reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: I think you can remove the line ```<picker:CustomPickerControl Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SelectedMealName, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate CustomPickerControl_Placeholder}" BorderColor="{x:StaticResource Gray400}" Padding="0, 0, 25, 0" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>``` as this is an own Control implementation. In case you want to see a replacement of this, you can use a simple ```<Entry />``` for that. The Button is a Standard Button. So, I think you should see something, now?

Comment: Yes, I replaced the `CustomPickerControl ` with an `Entry`, but I could only see the image  at the top of the screen.

Comment: Strange, that you could not see anything? The ContentView is hosted in a Main Page and displayed via Sharpnado Tabs and a TabHost/ViewSwitcher, so that the CalculateView is displayed. The CalculateView with the Code I've posted originally has the issue. At least you should see the white Frame with the rounded corners on top of a Background-Image.

Comment: Even if it does not work for you to put it together, are there general things or restrictions from these combinations of Layouts put inside of the other that could cause this behavior? So a question for instance is, why a Grid.Row=“0“ could be so far away from the upper border

Comment: It seems that when I remove the StackLayout as parent of my Frame and add ```VerticalOptions="Start"``` to the Frame it works at least in Portrait-View. When I put it in Landscape-View, the frame disappears, even when I add ```HorizontalOptions="Start"```, too

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I removed the StackLayout as parent of the Frame and added  `VerticalOptions="Start"` to the Frame, I still cannot see any controls underneath the image. Could you please post the full code of `yourContentView.xaml`?